# php regex - only 9 digits and ignore whitespace

Tags: php, regex

how to get 9 digit and ignore all white space between them ?

I use this pattern but not works !

```
/09([\d\S]{9})/g
```

text :
hello this is my number :  0933 55 261 33 and id is 79 ... end

I want get "33 55 26133"

Comment: Only like `if (preg_match('/09(?:\s*\d){9}/', $str, $m)){
    echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $m[0]);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Using `[\d\S]` will match either a digit or a non whitespace char, which by itself will also match a digit. You could write it as `\S{9}` which will not match a whitespace.

---

You can match 09, then forget what is matched until then using `\K`

Start the match with a single digit, and repeat optional horizontal whitespace chars followed by a digit 8 times.

```
\b09\K\d(?:\h*\d){8}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mi1E2Z/1)

```
$re = '/\b09\K\d(?:\h*\d){8}\b/';
$str = 'hello this is my number : 0933 55 261 33 and id is 79 ... end';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
33 55 261 33
```

To get the output in the question, you can remove the last space

```
$re = '/\b09\K\d(?:\h*\d){8}\b/';
$str = 'hello this is my number : 0933 55 261 33 and id is 79 ... end';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$match = preg_replace("~\h+(\d+)$~", "$1", $matches[0]);
echo $match;
```

Output

```
33 55 26133
```